# Need help designing a relational objects and classes for problem

Tags: .net, linq, class, object, model-view-controller

I need to create a page to display Committe List along with committee members(Employees) having different roles(picture)... I need assistance in  designing the classes for the same , like committee class, members class (who also are employees of the organization and their details are already saved in the employee class). Any help would be appreciated... [image]

i want to understand how to design the classes for the above structure...

Comment: Maybe you should add a sample data of your **employees**, so it can be check what you really need is. Also it needs to update table of your employees then joining them to make additional column of these *committee* in the table

Comment: @Newbee I hve name, department, details in employee table, I  wana display name of employee only

Comment: So we assume there's no problem with your data table, so what's PL you are using btw?

Comment: i use  .Net C# MVC .. I just need some help  creating classes for the same

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample for you by using a table variables
you can add foreign keys to normal tables, you need grouping set, because in your example you might have same committee with different roles

```
declare @Roles table (RoleID int identity (1,1), name varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY(RoleID))

insert into @Roles Values
('Convernor'), ('Co-Convenor'), ('Member'), ('Executive Member')

Select * from @Roles

declare @Members table (MemberID int identity (1,1), name varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY(MemberID))
insert into @Members Values
('Member1'), ('Member2'), ('Member3'), ('Member4')
select * from @Members

declare @Committie table (CommittieID int identity (1,1), CommittieName varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY(CommittieID))
insert into @Committie Values
('Committie-1'), ('Committie-2')
select * from @Committie

declare @Committies table (
      CommittiesID int identity (1,1)
    , groupingSet int 
    , CommittieID int not null 
    , MemberID int not null
    , RoleID int not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY(CommittiesID)
)
insert into @Committies (CommittieID, groupingSet,MemberID, RoleID) Values
(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1,2, 2), (1,1, 3, 3), (1,1, 4, 3)
,(2,2, 1, 1), (2,2, 2, 4), (2,2, 3, 3), (2,2, 4, 3)
,(1,3, 1, 1), (1,3, 2, 2), (1,3, 3, 3), (1,3, 4, 3)

select 
    list.groupingSet
    ,c.CommittieID
    ,c.CommittieName
    ,MemberName = m.name 
    ,RoleName = r.name
from @Committies list
Left Join @Committie c on c.CommittieID = list.CommittieID
Left Join @Members m on m.Memberid = list.MemberID
Left Join @Roles r on r.RoleID = list.RoleID
order by list.CommittiesID
```

results:

[image]

Comment: Thankx for the table design.. but actually i  am looking for some info creating classes and objects for the same .. l

Comment: classes, objects, etc.. which language? show what did you created?
 you can use EF to scaffold db - it will create set of DTO objects